# Is there a way to get Smarty syntax highlight in gedit?

Tags: gedit, syntax-highlighting, smarty

I'm using smarty to develop a website and I need syntax highlighting. Currently gedit only highlights the html. Since my tpl files contains only html and smarty template functions. 
I've Google'd for this functionality and found [this solution posted on github](https://github.com/dandelionmood/Smarty-syntax-coloration-for-GEdit), but I didn't get it to work.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

I just want a basic editor I don't care for fancy stuff that eclipse and other programs have. I just want a text editor with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the [github link](https://github.com/dandelionmood/Smarty-syntax-coloration-for-GEdit) to work. The steps I took was the following:

1. Copy the files to a folder.

   - [smarty.lang](http://pastebin.com/7FvX3DBG)
   - [smarty.xml](http://pastebin.com/1Lg4Megq)
   - [smarty.sh](http://pastebin.com/30CNhc7v)
2. Navigate to the folder with the `cd` command in a terminal.
3. Make smarty.sh executable

   `chmod +x ./smarty.sh`
4. And finally install it!

   `./smarty.sh`